# Single ScheduledExecutorService cannot complete its task (multiple removes from ArrayList<Object>)

Tags: java, multithreading

basically 3 threads are filling an ArrayList of custom object in concurrency and one single ScheduledExecutorService thread have to remove of the object from the ArrayList. I know there's a `removeAll()` method but I need to remove every object that verifies a condition based on the current system time.

Accesses of my list are handled by a `Semaphore(3)`. The list is filled by the following method implemented into an object called in the `static main`method of my main class:

```
public void addObject(Object object){
         try {
            //Thread.sleep(1000);
            sem.acquire();
            synchronized(this){
                objects.add(object);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            sem.release();
        }
     }
```

and this is the method to update my list:

```
public boolean updateObjects(){
     try {
        sem.acquire();
        synchronized(this){
            for(Object object : objects)
                if(objects.remove(object))
                    System.out.println(object.getId()+" removed.");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        sem.release();
    }

     return true;
 }
```

and this is my ScheduledExecutorService:

```
public class Scheduler implements Runnable{

    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    TradeFinder manager;

    public Scheduler(Manager manager){
        this.manager=manager;
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        //Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(manager.updateObjects()){
            System.out.println(sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis())+" LIST CLEARED.");
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }

}
```

but it will never print that because the `updateObject()`doesn't return true.
I also tried to implement an `equals()` method into the custom Object class:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(this.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(((*) obj).getId()))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

[(*) cast]

it will remove only the first object from the list.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `updateObjects` only has one `return` statement.  It can only return true.  However, it will always throw a ConcurrentModificationException unless `objects` is empty, because you are modifying the ArrayList while iterating over it.  If you want to remove all elements from an ArrayList, use its `clear()` method.

Comment: I get no ConcurrentModificationException during the execution. I need to remove only certain objects that verify a given condition based on time.

Comment: I suspect your `equals` method is faulty.  I don’t know the details of your data, but comparing one object’s `getId` value to another object’s `getUrl` value does not seem make sense to me.  In any event, if object equality is broken, nothing ever gets removed, which would explain the absence of a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: How do I define the `equals` method to get it works?

Comment: It’s your class.  What do you feel qualifies two instances of that class as representing the same data?

Comment: i edit the `equals` method please check.

Comment: Looks mostly correct.  Did it help with your overall issue?

Comment: To be honest: no haha. I thing using iterators is better and it is always dangerous to remove objects from a list while iterating over it.